# Powershell script not working to remove first 9 characters of certain files

Tags: powershell

I have files that I accidentally added dates to.

Example 20240325-*. *

I tried running this script in powershell and nothing happens:

```
Get-ChildItem -include "20*" | rename-item -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(9) }
```

I can't figure out why. Any help?

Comment: It works fine for me. Does `Get-ChildItem -include "20*"` by itself return anything for you? You can also try `Get-ChildItem -include "test*" | foreach {[string]($_.name).substring(9)}` to have it print out just the new names. Also: your example date only has 8 characters, so be careful you don't remove an extra one

Comment: Yes, {Get-Children  -include "20*"} gets the list of files I need to fix. But the rename does nothing at all. Could it be because I don't have administrative access?

Comment: This doesn’t necessarily help you fix your PowerShell script but there is a useful set of PowerShell scripts known as PowerToys by Microsoft which has a tool to rename files. It probably is a better solution to your overall problem, or the very least, will provide inspiration to solve your problem itself

Comment: I imaging PowerToys would be great, but I'm on a company computer that I can't install things on.

Comment: Got it to kind of work like this:

Get-ChildItem |Foreach-Object { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ([string] $_.BaseName.substring(9))  }

But now it takes off the extension

Comment: Now I think it's not getting the list of files. But when I run

Get-ChildItem -include "20*" -recurse

I get the list I expect.

Comment: Got it to work.          Get-ChildItem -include "20*" -recurse |Foreach-Object { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ([string] $_.Name.substring(9)) }          I don't know why I have to add the "-recurse" I also don't know how to include script in comments like @Cpt.Whale did

Comment: @BenH. Detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269209/using-get-childitem-exclude-or-include-returns-nothing/38308796#38308796

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!